# Programa de inicio tiene impacto alto al ejecutarse en segundo plano

Tags: python

Estoy creando un programa para que me cambie el fondo de pantalla automáticamente en segundo plano.
Cuando pongo la aplicación en inicio me pone que el impacto de la app es alta.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

La aplicación está copilada en *pyinstaller*

````
import random
import ctypes
import time
while True:
 wallpaper_folder = "\\Users\\cuent\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Imagenes de fondo" 
 os.chdir(wallpaper_folder)
 allowed_image_formats = ["jpg", "png", "jpeg"]
 list_of_images = [image for image in os.listdir() if image.endswith(tuple(allowed_image_formats))]
 random_wallpaper = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), random.choice(list_of_images))
 ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, random_wallpaper , 0)
 print("Se ha puesto el fondo llamado"+random_wallpaper)
 time.sleep(120)```
````

Comment: Algo de codigo al menos?

Comment: @jinXu Dale [edit] a tu pregunta y agrega ese código que colocaste en el comentario como la descripción de tu pregunta y le das formato de bloque de código. Visita el [tour] para que sepas como funciona SOes y de igual manera aprendas [ask].

Comment: ["High impact: Apps that use more than 1 second of CPU time or more than 3 MB of disk I/O at startup"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/w8cookbook/startup-apps?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: probá `win`+`R` `taskschd.msc` y crear task con trigger "at logon any user"

Comment: Quiero que sea automáticamente y lo haga el código automáticamente.Veras este .exe es como el segundo plano de un script aún más grande

Comment: Fíjate si con el scheduler  no protesta podes crear el task desde el main

Comment: Pero con la biblioteca?

Comment: fijate si te sirve https://stackoverflow.com/a/73596051/1423096 usa `subprocess.run` y el powershell para crear/editar tasks